# Active FPU Exceptions

Tags: delphi, exception, fpu

all fine?
Guys, would like to exchange an idea with yours. In my company, 
a colleague has a problem in your delphi where only on a project the exceptions of "Floating point divide by zero" are not showing up.

I checked everywhere I know where that could influence how:
**- Delphi Options -> Embarcadero Debuggers -> Language Exceptions.
- I tested the instruction System.Set8087CW ($ 1,372) to activate the FPU exceptions**

But it did not work. Does anyone have any tips on the cause of the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Either the 8087 zero divide exception is masked, or some exception handlers are handling the exceptions. I can't think of any other explanation.

Comment: It could be a DLL call that changes the 8087CW and does not revert it back on call exit. I've seen this happen with printer drives and network drivers. http://wiert.me/2009/05/06/delphi-michael-justin-had-strange-floating-point-results-when-his-8087-fpu-control-word-got-hosed/

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using and if it applies which platform (32/64)? Additionally it would help to know if this particular project has dependencies on external DLLs as mentioned by Jeroen.

Comment: Hi friends. I'll check your tips. We using Delphi XE with all updates. The problem happend in both windows, 64 and 32 bits. Thanks.

Comment: @Delphiman If you have XE your app is 32 bit only. Yes, 64 bit Windows runs 32 bit apps, but your app is 32 bit only.